# appfuse quickstart not working with mysql

Tags: mysql, maven, appfuse

I wanted to follow the quickstart guide. I'm using Linux, Java-7, Mysql 5.5 with root password (and do not want to remove it). I followed the instruction under "Create a project" with "BUILD SUCCESS"

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-jsf-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.2-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.atest -DartifactId=atest01 -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse
```

Then I changed at the end of pom.xml my root password correctly and run

```
mvn appfuse:full-source
```

I expected then to have some new databases in Mysql:

> "Maven will create and populate your database using the hibernate3 and
>   dbunit plugins, respectively."

But there is nothing, and all following steps do not work.

Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 1):

If you run "mvn install", the database should be created for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run from the root core module, not from web module, this maven command

```
mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl dbunit:operation -DskipTests=false
```

This will create your Db if not exist and populate you db with values of sample-data.xml file. I hope this will help you.